# How to escape underscore character in PATINDEX pattern argument?

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, escaping, sql-like

I've found a solution for finding the position of an underscore with PATINDEX :

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10)  
SET     @a = '37_21'

PRINT PATINDEX('%_%', @a)                    -- return 1 (false)
PRINT PATINDEX('%!%', REPLACE(@a, '_', '!')) -- return 3 (correct)
```

Have you other ideas? Like a way to escape the underscore character?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I've always done it with brackets: `'%[_]%'`

Comment: +1 see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx, Section "Searching for Wildcard Characters"

Answer (score 27):

To match two underscores, each must be bracketed

```
'%[__]%' -- matches single _ with anything after

'%[_][_]%' -- matches two consecutive _
```

Answer (score 6):

You can escape using the `[` and `]` characters like so:

`PRINT PATINDEX('%[_]%', '37_21')`

Comment: How do you escape the [ or ] characters itself then?