# SQL need to match the '-' char in patindex() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the patindex() function, where I'm matching for the `-` character.

```
select PATINDEX('-', table1.col1 )
from table1
```

Problem is it always returns 0.

The following also didn't work:

```
PATINDEX('\-', table1.col1 )
from table1
PATINDEX('/-', table1.col1 )
from table1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL : How to escape underscore character in PATINDEX pattern argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863534/t-sql-how-to-escape-underscore-character-in-patindex-pattern-argument)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-` character in a `PATINDEX` or `LIKE` pattern string outside of a character class has no special meaning and does not need escaping. The problem isn't that `-` can't be used to match the character literally, but that you are using `PatIndex` instead of `CharIndex` and are providing no wildcard characters. Try this:

```
SELECT CharIndex('-', table1.col1 )
FROM Table1;
```

If you want to match a pattern, it has to use wildcards:

```
SELECT PatIndex('%-%', table1.col1 )
FROM Table1;
```

Even inside a character class, if first or last, the dash also needs no escaping:

```
SELECT PatIndex('%[a-]%', table1.col1 )
FROM Table1;

SELECT PatIndex('%[-a]%', table1.col1 )
FROM Table1;
```

Both of the above will match the characters `a` or `-` anywhere in the column. Only if the pattern has characters on either side of the `-` inside a character class will it be interpreted as a range.

Comment: Cool, I never knew what Pat stood for.  CharIndex() works perfectly.

Comment: I agree it's better to use `CharIndex` when no pattern matching is needed.

Comment: This was driving me crazy!  I was trying to do an update with `REPLACE(Column, '[_]', ' ')` and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.  It should be `REPLACE(Column, '_', ' ')`.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the '-' as the first or last character within wildcard and it will work.

You can even use the below function to replace any special characters.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ReplaceSpecialCharacters](@Temp VarChar(200))
Returns VarChar(200)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(200)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[-,~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),!,?,.,,,+,\,/,?,`,=,;,:,{,},^,_,|]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0

    SET @Temp =REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE (REPLACE(REPLACE( @Temp, SUBSTRING( @Temp, PATINDEX( @KeepValues, @Temp ), 1 ),'')   ,' ',''),Char(10),''),char(13),''),'   ',''), '    ','')

Return REPLACE (RTRIM(LTRIM(@Temp)),' ','')
End
```

I am using in my project and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from another page here.

[How to escape underscore character in PATINDEX pattern argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863534/t-sql-how-to-escape-underscore-character-in-patindex-pattern-argument)

```
select PATINDEX('%[-]%', table1.col1 )
from table1
```

It seems to work, yet I have no idea why.

Comment: It's interesting that you provided a link to escaping, but didn't do any escaping...

Comment: The top answer (modified) gave me the solution, whatever it's called.

Comment: The reason this works is that you added `%` symbols inside the string. This turned it into a pattern, which is what `PatIndex` is looking for. Placing the `-` character inside a character class had no effect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but finding a helpful answer in the webiverse has proved fruitless and I want to spare the rest of the world the frustration.
I figured this out myself trying to create a check constraint to validate characters in a phone number - here's my pattern:

```
CONSTRAINT Chk_Mobile CHECK (PATINDEX('%[^0-9+() -]%',Mobile) = 0)
```

Basically when it comes to the dash, SQL interprets it as a range delimiter...
Unless you shove it at the **END** of your pattern.